# A doubt regarding $g−f$ where $g$ and $f$ are non-negative extended real valued measurable functions.

Tags: measure-theory

[image]

I'm stuck here in the part where it says $g = f + (g-f)$. My doubt is what happens if
$ \exists x_0$ such that $f(x_0) = +\infty$, then $g(x_0) = \infty$, so we will get $g(x_0) - f(x_0) = \infty - \infty$ (which isn't defined in my textbook). I know that since $f$ is non-negative measurable functions there exists increasing simple measurable functions $\phi_n \to f$ (pointwise), so for that particular $x_0$, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty} \phi_n (x_0) = \infty$ and I have a feeling that we might use $\int_X f d\mu <\infty$ and get a contradiction that $f(x) < \infty$ but I couldn't see it. Please help me out.

Comment: Please do not use images to convey information that is not otherwise present in your post. [See here for why this is bad practice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: Because $\int_X f\,d\mu\lt\infty$, you know that $f(x)$ is finite almost everywhere. You can use that to avoid those points.

Comment: my bad.,will try to update it asap @ArturoMagidin

Comment: I don't know about $f(x)$ being finite almost everywhere.  Can you please elaborate? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: If the set of points where $f(x)=\infty$, call it $K$, has $\mu(K)\gt 0$, what is $\int_Kf\,d\mu$? Now note that $\int_Kf(x)\,d\mu \leq \int_Xf\,d\mu$ because $f$ is nonnegative.

Comment: So $\int_X f \geq \int_K f = \int_X \chi_K f$ but $\chi_K f = \infty$ so $\int_X \chi_K f = \infty$ hence $\int_X f$ cannot be finite which is a contradiction. Is this correct? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: Yes, that is correct.